# need to get sum of all members of a dimension minus one member

Tags: mdx

I am trying to make an MDX query that can tell me how many products were sold in countries other than China. With the following query I can only get the units sold of bottled water for each of the countries, but not their sum. How do I modify the query to get the sum of that ?

```
SELECT NON EMPTY Except(
   {[Location].[All Places].Children}, 
   {[Location].[China]}
) ON COLUMNS,
  {[Product].[All Products].[Bottled Water].Children} ON ROWS
FROM [Places]
WHERE [Measures].[Units Sold]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want:

```
WITH 
  SET [countries] as Except( {[Location].[All Places].Children}, {[Location].[China]} )
  MEMBER [measures].[X] as Sum( [countries] , [Measures].[Units Sold] )

SELECT {[Product].[All Products].[Bottled Water].Children} ON ROWS 
FROM [Places] 
WHERE [measures].[x]
```